# Characters passing through objects - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, maya

I'm fairly new to Unity3d and I'm having trouble making my character stop passing through walls and houses that I imported from **Maya**, they all have Rigidbody, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the Rigidbody component, you'll need to attach Collider components to your objects. The best collider to use varies by object shape, so for some objects you might use a Box Collider while others would warrant a Sphere or Capsule Collider. When you attach a Collider component to an object, you'll see a green outline in the editor that shows you the shape of the collider as you adjust it.

There is also a Mesh Collider that uses the actual geometry of the model for collisions, but this is slow and has limitations. (*For one, mesh colliders can only collide with other mesh colliders if their "convex" flag is set*)

Another thing: The Rigidbody component only needs to be attached to objects that should move, such as the character. Walls and houses generally don't need the Rigidbody component.

If your character has Rigidbody and a Collider, and the walls/houses each have a Collider, then your character shouldn't pass through them.